# How to Show all Character Object in Print function

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a quick question, but after I try searching I can't find it anywhere.
my question is, how do I display all the character object strings in the print function in dart.?

this my example code :

```
...

String stepsVar = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.", 
print(stepsVar);

...
```

the console only shows a portion of characters and not all of them are displayed, How did it happen?
Thank you for the help.

best regard,

Comment: waht IDE are you using ? I'm using VSCode and I see all the characters

Comment: Use `debugPrint` instead of `print`

Comment: In Android Studio also - it shows full characters

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I'm using Android Studio. 
basically the code I wrote above is an example, but in my case I have a string with more than 5000 characters, but only half of it is displayed on the console, is there something wrong with the code or my editor's settings?

Comment: so did you use `debugPrint` as suggested above?

Comment: I have tried using the print function and debugPrint, but the result is the same, the console does not display all characters.

Comment: see [print and debugPrint with flutter logs](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging#print-and-debugprint-with-flutter-logs)